# MS Access Web Scraping -vba runtime error 91

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a small MS Access (Office 365) program to perform web page scrapes and store the results in Access tables.  The program looks up a web page then reads in any menu links.  However, when trying to do this I keep receiving the error:

Object variable not set (Error 91)

And this line gets highlighted:

```
Set arrAreas = vDiv.getElementsByClassName("rmLink rmRootLink")
```

This is the full code:

```
Private Function fx_Read_List()
    '------------< fx_Read_List() >------------
    
    '< get Menu >
    Dim vDiv As HTMLDivElement
    Set vDiv = hdoc.getElementById("ctl00_ctlMenu")
    
    '< get Menu-Area Links >
    Dim arrAreas As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set arrAreas = vDiv.getElementsByClassName("rmLink rmRootLink")
    '</ get Menu-Area Links >
    
    '< save in Array >
    Dim arrLinks() As String
    ReDim arrLinks(100)
    Dim iLink As Integer
    For iLink = 0 To arrAreas.length - 1
        Dim aLink As HTMLAnchorElement
        Set aLink = arrAreas(iLink)
        arrLinks(iLink) = aLink.hRef
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrLinks(iLink - 1)
    '</ save in Array >
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably it can't find element "ctl00_ctlMenu" in the HTML `Set vDiv = hdoc.getElementById("ctl00_ctlMenu")`

Comment: As said above. Put a breakpoint on `Dim arrAreas As ...` and as soon as you hit it, hover with your mouse over the `vDiv` object to see it's value.